# Flutter MaterialPageRoute with id of mysql to nextpage

Tags: php, mysql, json, flutter

I have develop a page SLIDESHOW use LISTVIEW that call a file json and php, it is work but I have a difficult..

On LISTVIEW, every photo is a code

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailEvento(id_evento: idPath),
      ),
    );
    print(idPath);
  },
```

idPath is a call number of ID MYSQL, on terminal is showed "I/flutter (4733): 435", debug iOS, I click on slideshow, go to page DetailEvento but don't showed ID...

On DetailEvento is code

```
 const DetailEvento({Key? key, required id_evento}) : super(key: key);

get id_evento => null;

print(id_evento.toString());
```

or

```
print(id_evento);
```

debug, is showed "I/flutter ( 4733): null"

Why? What did I do wrong?

I did a lot of research, nothing.